# Display Error getting while installing oracle 9i on centos 64 bit

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-9i

I want to install Oracle 9i on Centos using only command line. I tried to run installer using command line by silent but getting error as below.

```
[oracle@XXXXX]$ ./runInstaller -silent 
DISPLAY not set!
Please set DISPLAY and try again.
```

I tried to set DISPLAY variable by localhost in IP address but not able to connect X Server.
What is it that I miss?

Comment: How are you connected to the server? Console? PuTTY?

Comment: @macro I am Conneced with Putty.

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96167_01/inst.htm#sthref464) clearly describes how to install the database software non-interactively.

Oracle provides sample response files with the installation media, that you can customize and use as below:

`runInstaller -silent -responseFile enterprise.rsp`

If you omit the responsefile, the installer will try to start the interactive graphical installer, as there is no terminal based interactive installer (I wish there was...).